# Creating A Board Game

Tags: game-design, custom-game-pieces, game-development

I'm no expert in Board Game making and wanted to ask you people a question. I'm making a board game me and couple of friends can play. The problem is that i decided to keep 200 tiles for a very big experience unlike Snakes & Ladders which has only 100 tiles and LUDO which is full of repetition. Please don't take this the wrong way i love these games. So back to my game i decided that there would be a total of 90 tiles which includes 35 Good, 29 Bad & 24 Special tiles. Now i had envisioned that every floor which has 10 spaces each would have a even number of tiles regardless of them being good,bad or special but once i divided the total number of tiles which is 88 with 20 the number of floors i got 4.4. Its logically impossible to have 4.4 tiles on each floor. How can i solve this problem. 
Thank You In Advance for the answer

Answer (score 4):

> Now i had envisioned that every floor which has 10 spaces each would have a even number of tiles regardless of them being good,bad or special but once i divided the total number of tiles which is 88 with 20 the number of floors i got 4.4. Its logically impossible to have 4.4 tiles on each floor. How can i solve this problem.

Have a different number of tiles, then, that gives you a whole number result. Or simply don't use all the tiles - the leftover will result in each game potentially skewing toward more bad, good or special tiles than average.